# Tell Rollup to also transpile imported typescript packages

Tags: typescript, rollup, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I have an npm-workspaces based monorepo with two packages. `workspace-a` and `workspace-b`.

```
/
- package.json
- workspace-a/
   - package.json
   - index.ts
- workspace-b/
   - package.json
   - index.ts
   - rollup.config.js
```

`workspace-b` imports `workspace-a` as a dependency.
What I want is to use rollup to build `workspace-b`. For that to happen it needs to transpile the typescript in both itself, and the imported `workspace-a`.

Just using `@rollup/plugin-typescript` doesn't work, as it treats the imported `workspace-a` as a javascript dependency, and throws when it meets typescript specific syntax.

Ideally this would be possible, without adding a build step to `workspace-a`